# Reagent: Does defining a component inside another component cause performance issues?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, reagent

In Reagent, let's assume that I am defining a helper-function that returns a child component *within* a render function of the parent component.

Does this cause new child components to be generated every time the render function runs?

Here is a minimal example to illustrate:

```
(defn ChildComponent [text]
  [:p text])

(defn ParentComponent [names-vector]
  (let [renderChild (fn [i] 
                     [ChildComponent (get names-vector i)])]
    [:div
     [renderChild 1]
     [renderChild 3]
     [renderChild 5]]))
```

I have defined a `renderChild` function within the `let` as a helper function, to avoid duplicating the `(get names-vector i)` every time I use `ChildComponent`.

Preferably I'd like this to be almost exactly equivalent to:

```
(defn ChildComponent [text]
  [:p text])

(defn ParentComponent [names-vector]
  [:div
   [ChildComponent (get names-vector 1)]
   [ChildComponent (get names-vector 3)]
   [ChildComponent (get names-vector 5)]])
```

where a change in `names-vector` will potentially trigger a re-rendering of ChildComponents, but not destruction and creation.

Does Reagent expand the first example to the second?  Or are there potentially significant performance issues with the first example due to repeated component destruction/creation?

Answer (score 1):

<s>I've been using Reagent for about a year now, and I do exactly this kind of
thing.  I'd say it's the suggested thing to do even.  Reagent will also
implicitly uses the arguments as indicators to know whether to re-render the
component or not, so it's pretty optimized for knowing when to re-render.  Now,
my use case is probably smaller than some others out there, but I've been
extremely happy on the performance front with this kind of setup.  As best as I
can tell, it's the encouraged design pattern.</s>

<s>The one thing to watch out for is when dealing with a list of similar
elements (table row, item lists, etc.), you probably want to attach metadata to
uniquely identify each sibling.  React will use this under-the-hood to optimize
the rendering.</s>

<s>So, in your case, you may want something more like:</s>

```
[:div
 ^{:key 1} [renderChild 1]
 ^{:key 2} [renderChild 3]
 ^{:key 5} [renderChild 5]]))
```

**Update**

So, I misspoke: the issue with this technique is that a new function is created
every time the parent is re-rendered, which Reagent will see and be forced to
call the new function to get the potentially new children--since the "component"
appears to have changed.  I also did not use the functions in the same way the
original poster did.  Instead, when I needed to repeat elements, I opted for the
form:

```
(into []
      (for [i [1 3 5]]
        [ChildComponent (get names-vector i)]))
```

Or you could do the following instead:

```
(let [renderChild (fn [i]
                   [ChildComponent (get names-vector i)])]
 (into []
       (for [i [1 3 5]]
         (renderChild i))))
```

The first form simply avoids the extra function definition.  The second form
causes `renderChild` to be evaluated before returning the data, so Reagent never
sees the temporary function--thus side-stepping the need to have Reagent
evaluate it to find out the children haven't changed.

But in looking through the code for our app, we opted for the first form over
the second in all cases, or simply broke the function out and gave it a
name--where it made sense.

Also, this example is poor:

```
[:div
 ^{:key 1} [renderChild 1]
 ^{:key 2} [renderChild 3]
 ^{:key 5} [renderChild 5]]))
```

Adding keys only matters if the number of list elements is going to change.
AFAICT, React uses that information to help optimize the diff computation and
allows it to compute more easily which members need to be discarded and which
were added.  If it's static, then it doesn't matter.  A better example would be:

```
(into [:div]
      (for [val some-coll]
       ^{:key (compute-key val)} [:p (get some-other-coll val)]))
```

Where the contents of `some-coll` can change.

Comment: Thanks for sharing!  Great to know that the pattern has been used without noticeable issues in practice.  I guess I still have 2 nagging questions. 1) if the component type seems to have changed (renderChild appears to be a new function generated every time ParentComponent's render method runs), does Reagent properly cache the previous ChildComponent object and modify that?

Comment: 2) I have found explicit mention in both the React tutorial and the Reagent introduction that it's necessary for keys to be specified for dynamically generated list of components.  Does a set of similar components in a :div that is staticly specified like the examples above also benefit from specifying keys?

Comment: @zehnpaard 1) As I understand it, yes.  React renders everything to a faux DOM, then computes a diff.  But it's hard to actually verify that.  2) As far as I understand it, no.  It's really when the list of children can change that you get the benefit, so that the diff engine can use that to help optimize the diff created.  You don't have that issue with a static list.  So the example is probably poor here, but it's definitely the dynamic situation to be the most concerned about.  Keep in mind, this is my understanding of it all.  I still feel new to it, so I could have the details wrong. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have explored this issue further, and unfortunately it appears that Reagent does not cache components if the component definition occurs within the `let` bindings of another component's render function.

Sample code used for experimentation:

```
(defonce app-state (r/atom 0))

(defn Clicker []
  [:h2 {:on-click #(swap! app-state inc)} "Click me"])

(defn Displayer [n]
  (let [a (r/atom (js/console.log "Component generated!"))]
    (fn [n]
      [:p "Hello, yes I ignore my input"])))

(defn Intermediate1 [n]
  [Displayer n])

(defn Intermediate2 [n]
  (let [Subcomponent (fn [x] [Displayer x])]
    [Subcomponent n]))

(defn my-app []
  [:div
   [Clicker]
   [Intermediate2 @app-state]])

(r/render
  [my-app]
  (js/document.getElementById "app"))
```

With the `Intermediate1` component, the message "Component generated!" is displayed on the console log exactly once when the app is started.

Using `Intermediate2`, the console log shows "Component generated!" every time the `Clicker` component is clicked.

Adding `^{:key 1}` inside `Intermediate2` does not change the results:

```
   (defn Intermediate2 [n]
      (let [Subcomponent (fn [x] [Displayer x])]
        ^{:key 1} [Subcomponent n]))
```

This shows that the `Displayer` component is being destroyed and generated every time a new value is being sent to `Intermediate2`, which will trigger a re-rendering.  (Or rather, the rendering of a newly created component)

As such, while the cost may not be prohibitive in practice (particularly for generating a small number of simple components), it appears that binding components in a `let` inside render functions leads to unnecessary component destruction/creation, potentially negating the efficiency benefits of using a React style virtual DOM.

Comment: RIght... So, part of the issue here is that using the let form you're creating a new function every time the outer component is rendered, and Reagent sees that.  So the data to it didn't change, but the actual function identity did.  Sorry for missing that aspect of the problem.  However, you can immediately evaluate the outer portion so that the function is expanded to real components whose definitions don't change  For instance, `Subcomponent` directly (`(Subcomponent n)` vs `[Subcomponent n]`).  I wouldn't really call it a subcomponent in this case though.

Answer (score 0):

Please read about this link before asking question.

https://github.com/Day8/re-frame/wiki/Creating-Reagent-Components#the-three-ways

A block of data structure or a function return block of data structure will be consider as `Form-1`. All will be expanded as a single data structure. Any ratom change within this scope will trigger re-render of this single data structure.

> Does this cause new child components to be generated every time the render function runs?

Yes. `renderChild` will be re-created due to the `Form-1` nature.

> I have defined a renderChild function within the let as a helper function, to avoid duplicating the (get names-vector i) every time I use ChildComponent.

If you want any one of `ChildComponent` will only be re-render when its own value of `(get names-vector i)` is changed, but not by the changes in parent or siblings. You should use `Form-2`, or `Form-3`. (**the names-vector must be a ratom to make reagent to work!**)

```
(defn ChildComponent [names-vector i]
  (fn [names-vector i]
    [:p (get @names-vector i)]))

(defn ParentComponent [names-vector]
  [:div
   [ChildComponent names-vector 1]
   [ChildComponent names-vector 3]
   [ChildComponent names-vector 5]])
```